# EmbeddedChannel and channelActive

Tags: java, netty

I am writing unit test for my application using `EmbeddedChannel`:

```
@Test
public void sendMessage() {
    CurrentMessage currentMessage = new CurrentMessage();
    currentMessage.setCommand(CommandEnum.CURRENT_MEASUREMENT_REQUEST);

    EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel();
    channel.pipeline().addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.TRACE));
    channel.pipeline().addLast(new ClientEventHandler(currentMessage));
    assertTrue(channel.isActive());
}
```

But my `channelActive` from `ClientEventHandler` is no invoked:

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    IConverter converter = CommandUtil.commands.get(message.getCommand().getHexValue());

    byte[] byteMessage = converter.encode(message);

    logger.info("Sending byte array message: " + byteMessage);

    ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(byteMessage));
}
```

Does `EmbeddedChannel` supports `channelActive` or `channelRegister`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A EmbeddedChannel is active after its constructed so the handlers you are added are added too late. Add them via the constructor and it should work:

```
EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(
        new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.TRACE),
        new ClientEventHandler(currentMessage));
```